# Purchasing Borland C++ Builder v6 Personal

Tags: c++builder

We need to support and update the old but still perfectly working project written many years ago using Borland C++Builder 6 Personal. No new significant development is expected. Switching to RAD Studio is taking much more effort than just keep using the old stuff.

Is there any option to legally purchase Borland C++Builder or whatever, but register and keep using the old stuff?

Comment: Even if you own a legally purchased copy of C++ Builder 6 they refuse the registration process which is necessary for using it. They literarlly hate their customers.

Comment: @ Herwig I'm afraid you're correct. And not only "they" but almost all of them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any option to legally purchase BCPP Builder or whatever but register and keep using the old stuff?

Not directly, no.  The old products are long dead.  They are no longer sold or supported.

However, if you purchase the latest RAD Studio version, you can get licenses for old versions, including C++Builder 6.  See the following page for more details:

https://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/previous-versions

Comment: Doesn't make too much sense. The price for RAD is high even not counting development time for conversion from the old stuff to new, features from the new stuff required ==0...